# CSS - Why I see the dash-line when I click a Link with Firefox

Tags: css

Test(XXX)

```
#b1-wrap {
cursor:pointer;
height:107px;
left:573px; // this seems that the dash-line is caused by the margin on the left.
position:absolute;
top:17px;
width:310px;
}
```

When the user clicks the text Test, the user will trigger a.php.
Here is the problem, when I click the link without releasing my mouse in firefox, I can see a dash-line across the left.

Please see the screenshot http://i56.tinypic.com/w8kpiw.png
I cannot figure out why? and how to fix it?

Anyone can help?

this seems that the dash-line is caused by the margin on the left because if I increase the value of left, I can see the dash-line expanded. So is there a fix for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try css on the `a` tag

```
outline: none
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_outline.asp

Comment: hello babtek, what is the best location I should use this rule. I mean which tag I need to use to apply this rule? thank you

Comment: @q0987 if you never want to see it, try `a {outline:none;}` or specifically in this case, `a.header{outline:none;}`.

Comment: yes I would agree, this outline property is coming from a browser default on the a tag, so depending on how specific you want to get you can apply to all on the page or just this one. I might do h1.header a.header {outline:none;}

Answer (score 1):

The "dash-line" you are referring to is the focus border that indicates which element has the focus. It usually appears on links and not on `div`s, so you should look at the CSS for your link. It's size is the same as the bounding box of the element, so try adjusting the position/size of the link.